# SQL CLR for mongodb throwing 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer' exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, sqlclr

I'm using C# to create a SQL CLR procedure to do some basic operations on MongoDB like get the contents of a collection, inserting a document etc.
but I'm getting ***The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer' threw an exception.***

**Any ideas ??**

The exact same code from C# directly works fine.

I'm using C# driver for Mongo version 1.10, .NET Framework 3.5, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM).

Below you may find a sample of the stack trace:

Failed to delete collection from DB
Error :The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer' threw an exception.   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(Type type)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase.DropCollection(String collectionName)
   at Mongo.Test()

Getting Collections from DB
Failed to Get collection from Database
Error :The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer' threw an exception.   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(Type type)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command, ReadPreference readPreference)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Count(CountArgs args)
   at Mongo.Test()

Inserting document to collection ...
Failed to insert into the collection of DB test_blobs
Error :Unable to connect to server xx.local:27017: The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer' threw an exception..   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.ChooseServerInstance(ReadPreference readPreference)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.AcquireConnection(ReadPreference readPreference)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.InsertBatch(Type nominalType, IEnumerable documents, MongoInsertOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert(Type nominalType, Object document, MongoInsertOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert[TNominalType](TNominalType document)
   at Mongo.Test()

Comment: Is the assembly containing the `MongoDB` namespace registered as `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE`? I believe it is complaining about something in the class constructor for `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer` which should be the method starting with `static BsonSerializer()`. What is happening in that method?

Comment: @srutzky, Yes, the assembly is UNSAFE. I don't know what is happening inside that method because that one comes as is from the C# dll driver of MongoDB. I discovered that with newer sql version which supports newer .NET framework and with the latest MongoDB driver v2.0, the above works fine. Though, I need this to work with SQL 2008

Comment: Well, the .NET driver is open source, so you _can_ know what it is doing by going here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master ;-). I would suggest grabbing that source and trying to compile it after changing the `TargetFrameworkVersion` to .NET 3.5. If the code is using something new in v4.0 or newer, then you should get a compile error and hence your answer ;-)

Comment: @srutzky, yes that was a good idea but unfortunately the compilation errors were too much to bother with it :P Anyway, most probably I will look for other alternatives, thx for your suggestion

Comment: I just looked again and noticed a note about the 1.x series being the last to use .NET 3.5. If you grabbed the latest based on the link that I posted above, then it was the 2.x series. So try this link which is the last 1.10.x release. The code from here should compile as the target is already .NET 3.5: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/v1.10.0

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the issue, or at least part of it, is that starting in the 2.x series of the **.NET Driver for MongoDB**, the Target Framework Version changed to 4.5.

So there are two possibilities:

1. If you really need to get this working in SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2, then you can grab the source code for 1.10 version of the **.NET Driver for MongoDB**, found at:
   https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/v1.10.0
   That is the last version to use .NET Framework Version 3.5.
2. Since it seems that the 2.x series of the **.NET Driver for MongoDB** does work in the newer versions of SQL Server (2012 and newer, I assume), you do have the option of:

   - installing SQL Server 2014 (or soon to be 2016) Express Edition (the free version)
   - loading a 2.x version of the **.NET Driver for MongoDB** onto that Express Edition instance
   - and then setting up a Linked Server from the SQL Server 2008 instance to the SQL Server 201[2,4,6] Express Edition, and hence use the Express Edition as a proxy

Comment: Like I said, I used version 1.10 and it didn't work for me. As for the option 2, I ain't looking for that kind of workaround... :(

Comment: @ChrisM I didn't think option 2 was all that bad :-(. In fact, I kinda think it would work out nicely as it isolates the UNSAFE SQLCLR stuff externally from the main instance. For option 1, I was just thinking that maybe doing a local compile of 1.10 might give more explicit error messages / insight than _The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer' threw an exception._